# Using HTMLUnit to test Java script

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I'm trying to learn how to use HTMLUnit in order to test some website's JavaScripts elements.

I've tried doing some homework and using the HTMLUnit's How-To's but with no success. I get stuck when trying to run my program, I need to choose how to run it and it gives me a list of option which I never handled before. Please help me on this?

All, I get is a console window waiting for some input? Thats not what I was expecting to happen obviously.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding @Test above the homePage() method?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) to test Javascript - that's what the jQuery team uses.